# How to use getInitialProps in React component

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js

this is my first time working with React and Next.js so I'm not very experienced, but I'm trying to help out with a project that uses both of these things. I need to get an array of artists from an endpoint and use it in `ProjectForm`. The `getInitialProps` function is used to do this elsewhere in the project, so I'm attempting to follow suit, but am not sure how to pass this data to `ProjectForm`. I've tried things like `const ProjectForm = (props: ProjectFormProps, artists)` and adding `artists: artists` to the `ProjectFormProps`, but no dice. How can I use the `artists` data I'm getting from the `getInitialProps` function within `ProjectForm`? Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

interface ProjectFormProps {
  entity: any;
  user: any;
  projectTypes?: any;
  handleButtonClick?: any;
  isNew?: boolean,
  onSubmitForm?: Function,
  onChange?: Function,
};

const ProjectForm = (props: ProjectFormProps) => {

  console.log(artists);

  return (
    <h1>Artists</h1>
  );
}

ProjectForm.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
  const baseUrl = req ? `${req.protocol}://${req.get('Host')}` : '';
  const artists = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/api/artists`)
    .then(res => res.data)
    .catch(err => console.error(err, 'Unable to retrieve artists from API.'));
  return {
    artists
  };
};

export default ProjectForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
interface ProjectFormProps {
  entity: any;
  user: any;
  projectTypes?: any;
  handleButtonClick?: any;
  isNew?: boolean,
  onSubmitForm?: Function,
  onChange?: Function,
  artists?: any
};


const ProjectForm = (props: ProjectFormProps) => {
  console.log(props.artists);

  return (
     <h1>Artists</h1>
  );
}
```

Comment: Check if you are actually getting artists in getInitialProps

Comment: If yes, then instead of console.log(props.artists); check console.log(props); for artists parameter

Comment: `console.log(props.artists);` gives me `undefined` and I'm not seeing an artists parameter when I check `console.log(props);`.

Comment: Yeap, I have also tried on sandbox. I think the issue is with setup of our app, because for some reason getInitialProps is not getting executed at all. May be you need to check for installation and make sure that everything works fine (mainly getInitialProps gets executed)